# How can I disable dates prior to the current one in a datedit devexpress?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have tried to investigate about it but I can't find the solution, I have a dateedit control that has an ID called datebegin so I want in the c# code to be able to indicate that the previous dates be disabled to the current

Answer (score 0):

MinValue will disable(make white space) over all date before of the assigned. This will probably work.

```
DateEdit1.Properties.MinValue=Now() 'This is a vb.net code
```